# Validação de data com DataAnnotation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, validação, annotation

Queria saber se tem como validar se a Data inserida é maior ou não que a data atual usando Annotation, ou se eu tenho que tratar no controller mesmo. Se tiver como, disponibilize um exemplo por favor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer isso criando uma classe que deriva de `RangeAttribute`:

```
public class DateAttribute : RangeAttribute
{
    public DateAttribute()
      : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.MaxValue.ToShortDateString()) { }
}
```

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406046/data-annotation-ranges-of-dates)

Comment: Eu gostei dessa resposta aqui também, mas está no SOF em Inglês. Não sei qual é a política de uso das informações da comunidade em inglês aqui no pt.SOF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19882296/mvc4-data-annotation-compare-two-dates

Comment: @StillBuggin Eu meti o link para a pergunta na minha resposta